# Verify that header only contains one value in Wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm looking for an easy way to verify that a request was made with only one value for a specific header.

The below snippet passes when the 'Authorization' header has multiple values.

```java
verify(
    getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/url"))
        .withHeader("Authorization", equalTo("Bearer token"))
);
```

I could take the custom matcher approach but I would say its not exactly ideal and it produces an error message that doesn't really capture the situation very well.

```java
verify(
    getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/url"))
        .withHeader("Authorization", equalTo("Bearer token"))
        .andMatching(r -> MatchResult.of(r.getHeaders().getHeader("Authorization").isSingleValued()))
);
```

I'm surprised the `equalTo` matcher cant be used to verify a single header value and the `contains` matcher cant be used when multiple values are expected.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?